# How do I change robots.txt on a Google site?

Tags: robots.txt

I need to make changes to someone's robot.txt file, but their site is managed by Google, (so no FTPing).

I have full access to the site via the browser (Site Actions / Manage Site, etc) but how do I get to the robots.txt file to update it?

Comment: Try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: OP posted [this question on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99481/17633).